# Merging pandas columns (many-to-one)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, repeat

I have two dataframes:

df1

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

df2:

```
Name  Count
raj       2
dinesh    3
sachin    3
glen      2
```

Now I want to create a third dataframe with parent dataframe as df1 with second column inserted as "Owner" with 2 rows assigned to raj, 3 to dinesh, 3 to sachin and 2 to glen. The third datframe will look like this:

df3:

```
ID     Owner
1      raj
2      raj
3      dinesh
4      dinesh
5      dinesh
6      sachin
7      sachin
8      sachin
9      glen
10     glen
```

I'll highly appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) but is necessary sum of all `Count` values is same as length of `df1`:

```
df1['Owner'] = np.repeat(df2['Name'].values, df2['Count'].values)
print (df1)
   ID   Owner
0   1     raj
1   2     raj
2   3  dinesh
3   4  dinesh
4   5  dinesh
5   6  sachin
6   7  sachin
7   8  sachin
8   9    glen
9  10    glen
```

Comment: yes, the count values in second dataframe are always same as length of first dataframe. Thanks, I am now testing your suggestion and get back to you in a while.

Comment: It is giving me an error:Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: If use only `print (np.repeat(df2['Name'].values, df2['Count'].values))` it works?

Comment: It is giving me an error:Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'And when I change the dtype of count variable from int64 to int32, it does the trick but gives me SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Comment: Can you add your code whar return error? And obviously error is in one rows above, so is possible post code block?

Comment: Sure, below is the code </br>
`cne['Owner'] = np.repeat(cne_hunters['User ID'].values, cne_hunters['Count'].values) </br`

As it is, the above code is having problems, but if I write the below line first </br>
`cne_hunters['Count'] = cne_hunters['Count'].astype(np.int32)` </br>
It works, but gives me SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: And row of code before `cne_hunters['Count'] = cne_hunters['Count'].astype(np.int32)` ?

Comment: Or try intead `cne['Owner'] = np.repeat(cne_hunters['User ID'].values, cne_hunters['Count'].values)` use `cne = cne.assign(Owner=np.repeat(cne_hunters['User ID'].values, cne_hunters['Count'].values))`

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!